# Handling images in .NET MAUI in a memory efficient and smooth way

Tags: maui

I'm planning an app which needs to show quite a few images, think a CD register with pictures of covers.
I can see how I can load an image from a stream and load it into the `Source` property of an `Image` using something like,
`ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);`
This works, but the problem is that it's not memory efficient to load several MBs of a high-resolution photo only to let the `Image` scale it down to thumbnail size. I would prefer if `FromStream` could scale down the image on the fly and only return the scaled-down image.
My question is if it is possible to efficiently load scaled-down images - preferably in a cross-platform way?

I found [one library](https://github.com/Redth/FFImageLoading.Compat) that may do what I want and much more - is that what I should use?
I found [a great description](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics) of how it could be done, but it's pretty low-level and Android specific, so the suggestion is to use [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) instead.
Glide will presumably do exactly what I want, but Glide is Android only - and MAUI is using Glide under the hood, so using it directly is not the MAUI way.
I found `LoadThumbnail` in the Android SDK. This API seems to work fine, but still - not cross-platform.

Comment: where are your images coming from?  Are you loading them from urls, from pre-loaded images in the app, or from images downloaded to the filesystem?

Comment: For now, I'm loading them from the local file system.

Comment: then why don't you resize the source files appropriately?

Comment: I should probably have described that more clearly. What I want is to have a fast and efficient way to show a (large) number of thumbnail pictures. But I still need full sized pictures for other purposes. It's a good idea to also store scaled down pictures. It may be that I will have to spend the storage space needed for that. Thanks.

Comment: @belgaard It is not only about memory efficiency. Try to put very high resolution image, and you will start getting runtime exceptions. I have similar app for shopping. The images you see are pre-scaled to something like 100x100, the backend does this when the item is added to the database. When the item is clicked, full resolution image is displayed. But for me this is backend job. To control what is allowed and what not. Something like 3000x3000 makes some old but supported Android devices just throw unhandled exception and its over.

Comment: That's a good point@H.A.H. I need to add such test cases. I cannot upload thumbnails in advance as the user is supposed to pick pictures from local storage, at least in the first MVP. However, it will typically be photos taken with the local device so I guess the problem with huge images will not typically be a problem.

Comment: Some image file formats, including jpegs have techniques for embedding thumbnails as part of the file format. In some JPEGs they place that in the "gap" that's between the EXIF headers and the start of the image data. Being able to render the thumbnail section will achieve what you need, i.e. low memory and render time for a rapid preview. You will have to review thumbnail formats that are available to you.